# Python groupby turns dataframe to a weird object

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

i have this code :

```
df = df.sort_values(['CUST','FT','DATE'])
df = df.groupby(['CUST', 'FT', 'DATE']).agg({'QTY': ['sum']})
df
```

After the sort, i group by and print the table, i want to have further manipulation but python
only recognizes QTY inside df object. I need the object to be a DataFrame.
This is how it looks like :

[image: Output]

The error i get for trying to engage CUST for example :
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'CUST'.

what is the problem ? what am i doing wrong ?
how do i deal with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use reset_index, or to insert as_index=False inside the groupby as
did i.

```
df = df.groupby(['CUST', 'FT', 'DATE'], as_index=False).agg({'QTY': ['sum']})
```